# Смещение элемента с CSS clip-path

Tags: html, css

Есть слайдер, где фон элемента задан через `after` с использованием свойства `clip-path`.
В Firefox при скролле до конца страницы этот фон смещается, из-за чего появляется полоса.(см. скриншот).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из-за чего это происходит?

```js
$('.js--bg-slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.js--info-slider',
  arrows: false,
  fade: true,
  infinite: false
});
$('.js--info-slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.js--bg-slider',
  arrows: false,
  dots: true,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  infinite: false,
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.l-categories {
  padding: 5rem 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.b-categories {
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.b-categories::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: .15;
  content: '';
  z-index: 1;
}

.b-categories::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 40%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  content: '';
  clip-path: polygon(10% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  z-index: 2;
}

.b-categories__hero-holder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.b-categories__hero-img {
  max-width: none;
}

.b-categories__container {
  height: 100%;
}

.b-categories__info-holder {
  max-width: 580px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.b-categories__hero-slider,
.b-categories__info-slider {
  width: 100%;
}

.b-info {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.b-info__link {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 18px 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.4-rc1/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.js"></script>
<section class="l-categories gap">
  <div class="b-categories">
    <div class="b-categories__hero-holder">
      <div class="b-categories__hero-slider js--bg-slider">

        <div class="b-categories__hero-item">
          <img class="b-categories__hero-img" src="https://placeholdit.co//i/1920x500?bg=41ace4">
        </div>
        <div class="b-categories__hero-item">
          <img class="b-categories__hero-img" src="https://placeholdit.co//i/1920x500?bg=3838ca">
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="b-categories__container grid-container clearfix">
      <div class="b-categories__info-holder float-right">
        <div class="b-categories__info-slider js--info-slider">

          <div class="b-categories__info-item">
            <div class="b-info">
              <h2 class="b-info__title">Lorem impsum 1</h2>
              <p class="b-info__desc text-justify">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. A, praesentium. Possimus modi delectus error itaque suscipit dolorem magni cum ex soluta quia, voluptatibus asperiores veniam adipisci eveniet quas culpa quasi.
              </p>
              <div class="b-info__link-holder text-right">
                <a href="#" class="b-info__link h-shadow">View colection</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="b-categories__info-item">
            <div class="b-info">
              <h2 class="b-info__title">Lorem impsum 2</h2>
              <p class="b-info__desc text-justify">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. A, praesentium. Possimus modi delectus error itaque suscipit dolorem magni cum ex soluta quia, voluptatibus asperiores veniam adipisci eveniet quas culpa quasi.
              </p>
              <div class="b-info__link-holder text-right">
                <a href="#" class="b-info__link h-shadow">View colection</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: вообще clip-path косяковый же ... если это возможно то не использовать его вообще

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, заменил `clip-path` на svg, проблема осталась.